Loading dll from one project works but from the other does not
I am trying to load a .dll file in one of my projects like the following.
import ctypes
dll_path = r'C:\path_to_dll'
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(dll_path)

However, I get the error message
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\ws0734\source\repos\c-gurobi-matlab\C_dll_project\C_dll_project\x64\Release\Cdllproject.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.

But if I try to load the same .dll file from another project it does work, surprisingly. I am using the same anaconda environment in both projets and same vscode settings to run the file. I looked at the environment variables using os.environ but I can´t seem to find out what the difference between the two is exepct the different working direction. Any suggestions to trouble shooting would really help.

[SO]: Discover missing module using command-line ("DLL load failed" error) (@CristiFati's answer) might help

windows perhaps,  change the back slash to forward slash /.

@darren, unfortunately does not change anything.

@CristiFati, thanks for the link but I think it´s not the .dll that is the problem since it does work from another workspace, right?

I don't know (there are too many unknowns, workspace setting, how code is run, ...). But this is a troubleshoot step which may or may not get you closer to identifying the problem. Clearly, not doing it, won't.
